# Does $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x^2-1)}{(x-1)^2}dx$ converge absolutely; converge?

Tags: calculus, integration

This is a self-review exercise in my textbook I've been unable to solve:

> Does $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x^2-1)}{(x-1)^2}dx$ converge absolutely? Converge?

I tried separating the integral to $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin(x^2-1)}{(x-1)^2}dx+\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x^2-1)}{(x-1)^2}dx$. Intuitively it looks like you can use the comparison test to show $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin(x^2-1)}{(x-1)^2}dx$ doesn't converge absolutely/converge? So the answer is a double no. But intuition isn't a proof, unfortunately, so I'm stuck...

In any case, can anyone explain how this question can be solved?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hint: as $x \to 1$, $\frac{\sin(x^2-1)}{(x-1)^2} \sim \frac{2}{x-1}$ using $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}$.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try using your hint and come back if I run into trouble!

Comment: I used your hint and found that $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{sin(x^2-1)}{(x-1)^2}dx$ doesn't absolutely converge. Because $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{|sin(x^2-1)|}{(x-1)^2}dx=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{sin(x^2-1)}{(x-1)^2}dx$ this means the integral doesn't converge either. And this means $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{sin(x^2-1)}{(x-1)^2}dx$ neither converges absolutely nor converges. Is this correct?

Comment: @Dever how did you solve the question in the end?